# Активировать кнопку при заполнении инпута

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть input'ы в которых вводится что либо. Есть кнопка (submit) нажатием на которую данные отправляются куда нужно. Собственно охота узнать, как сделать, кнопку не нажимающейся, в случае если input'ы не заполнены? Именно input'ы, т.е. несколько и name там все время разные

Comment: смотри валидацию форм.onsubmit="return fn()",где fn функция проверка полей

Comment: я для подобных целей использую backbone примерно следующим образом: [demo](http://jsbin.com/afetez/2/edit), но достичь подобного эффекта можно и без него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут подготовил для Вас рабочый пример: http://jsfiddle.net/tVkY3/2/

Comment: огромное спасибо. теперь буду знать как делать. ест-но я немного переписал под себя

Comment: @dpetruk, а что если для каждого инпута своя специфическая валидация нужна?